# Weird Javascript expression

Tags: javascript, function, syntax

I try to understand how [Protovis](http://vis.stanford.edu/protovis/ex/force.html) works, and I stumbled upon code like this:

```
force.node.add(pv.Dot)
    .size(function(d) (d.linkDegree + 4) * Math.pow(this.scale, -1.5)) // notice this
    .fillStyle(function(d) d.fix ? "brown" : colors(d.group)) // and this
    .strokeStyle(function() this.fillStyle().darker()) // and even this
    .lineWidth(1)
    .title(function(d) d.nodeName)
    .event("mousedown", pv.Behavior.drag())
    .event("drag", force);
```

I tried rolling my own short functions, like this:

```
(function(a) a+2)
```

I am **NOT** asking about anonymous functions declared like `function(){stuff();}`. The code in question looks like `function() stuff;` and it works. I want to know why. I don't want to learn about constructs like `myvar = function(a){return a+1;}`, but about constructs like `myvar = (function(a) a+1)`. Please look at the above code more carefully.

But, as I suspected, it threw a syntax error.

How can such code work?

(*Note: the protovis code **does** work as intended.*)

Comment: I don't get it. I even checked the grammar specified in the spec - the braces *are* required for anonymous functions: http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/ECMA-262.pdf "A.5 Functions and Programs".

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is a Expression Closure that was introduced in JavaScript 1.8. It is an extension to ECMAScript.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/New_in_JavaScript/1.8

Comment: Finally. an answer that understood the question!

Comment: @lincolnk - For compatibilities sake that is true but something like this should really be built into ECMAScript.

Comment: why? trading explicitness for shorter code seems like a bad trade.

Comment: @lincolnk - I am of the camp that feels that core language features should be as short as possible but no shorter. Have you ever seen a considerably sized project that didn't use lambdas all over the place? The expression closure syntax is still a bit heavy because of the `function` keyword but the majority of the noise is removed. The same idea is used in C# with lambda expressions.

Comment: I'm all for short lambdas. But this still sounds like a bad idea, especially since they didn't shorten the `function`, which is about as long the braces and the `return`. Real solution: use Coffeescript :)

Answer (score 2):

Protovis also has its own code to handle the case where the browser you're running does not yet support the Expression Closure format, here: http://vis.stanford.edu/protovis/jsdoc/symbols/src/src_pv-internals.js.html

Comment: Thanks! I was stumped trying to determine what `<script type="text/javascript+protovis">` meant, and how it worked. I incorrectly assumed it was something to do with XML namespaces in XHTML...

Answer (score 1):

This is an Expression Closure, see this:

- http://asserttrue.blogspot.com/2009/07/javascript-expression-closures-and-why.html

Here's the jsfiddle that works:

- http://jsfiddle.net/fyB9h/